# HTML to PDF - CSS in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, html, css, height, itext

I am trying to build a pdf file from html code using iTextSharp.

Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<div style="height:400px; font-family:Courier; font-size:9px">
    herrow
</div>
<span style="padding-left:100px;">
    world
</span>
```

Running as an html file it works fine putting 400px between hello and world and 100px before world.

Here is the code I am using to convert the html to pdf:

```
    List<IElement> htmlList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), new StyleSheet());

    foreach (IElement element in htmlList)
    {
        doc.Add(element);
    }
```

It does apply the font-family and font-size in the resulting pdf.
However, it ignores the div height and the span width in the pdf that is produced.

Is it possible to use heights / widths / padding etc., when converting html to pdf with iTextSharp?

If not is there a work around, or another free .dll that I can use to do this?

Comment: HTMLWorker is deprecated and not supported anymore, instead look into  XMLWorker. http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html

Comment: same problem here... Is that use of XMLWorker will solve this?? how to use it??

Comment: Try [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/): a replacement and/or a testing for your html2pdf renderization.

Answer (score 2):

Just pull out height attribute outside the style tag and use it like this:-

```
<div height='400' style="font-family:Courier;font-size:9px">
```

herrow

```
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using iTextSharp, you may want to take a look at PhantomJS. It's a different approach but it is really helpfull! No more problems with css.

Take a look at this: [phantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646375/generating-pdfs-using-phantom-js-on-net-applications/19933888#19933888).

Comment: that would create an image? in that case the pdf wouldn't have selectable text, right?