# Generating PDFs using Phantom JS on .NET applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, phantomjs

I have been looking into phantomJS and looks like it could be a great tool to use generating PDFs. I wonder if anyone have successfully used it for their .NET applications.

My specific question is: how would you use modules like [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) on the server, receive requests and send back generated pdfs as a response.

My general question is: is there any best practice for using phantomJS with .NET Applications. What would be the best way to achieve it?

I am fairly new in .NET World and I would appreciate the more detailed answers. Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know about best practices, but, I'm using phantomJS with no problems with the following code.

```
public ActionResult DownloadStatement(int id)
{
    string serverPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Phantomjs/");
    string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss") + ".pdf";

    new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(x =>
    {
        ExecuteCommand("cd " + serverPath + @" & phantomjs rasterize.js http://localhost:8080/filetopdf/" + id.ToString() + " " + filename + @" ""A4""");
    })).Start();

    var filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Phantomjs/"), filename);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] bytes = DoWhile(filePath);

    return File(bytes, "application/pdf", filename);
}

private void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
        Process Process;

        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
    }
    catch { }
}

public ViewResult FileToPDF(int id)
{
    var viewModel = file.Get(id);
    return View(viewModel);
}

private byte[] DoWhile(string filePath)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    bool fail = true;

    while (fail)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            }

            fail = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    return bytes;
}
```

Here is the action flow:

The user clicks on a link to `DownloadStatement Action`. Inside there, a new `Thread` is created to call the `ExecuteCommand` method.

The `ExecuteCommand` method is responsible to call phantomJS. The string passed as an argument do the following.

Go to the location where the phantomJS app is and, after that, call `rasterize.js` with an URL, the filename to be created and a print format. ([More about rasterize here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture)).

In my case, what I really want to print is the content delivered by the `action` filetoupload. It's a simple action that returns a simple view. PhantomJS will call the URL passed as parameter and do all the magic.

While phantomJS is still creating the file, (I guess) I can not return the request made by the client. And that is why I used the `DoWhile` method. It will hold the request until the file is created by phantomJS and loaded by the app to the request.

Comment: You could use Process.WaitForExit instead of a do while loop. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This does not work when the application is run in IIS on Windows Server 2008+. This solution works when you test it from visual studio but will not work in production when deployed to IIS, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5308011/1062224.

Comment: We are using it since the date I posted this answer and it's working fine.

Comment: @Filepe Miosso what version of Windows Server, IIS and .NET framework are you using?

Comment: We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 and .NET 4.0. Just an observation... The code I've posted is being used by a .NET MVC application and not a Windows Service.

Comment: I've tried this in an MVC Controller without success too, using the same code you've supplied. My setup is Windows Server 2012, IIS 8, MVC 5.2. I then tried to do this from a self hosted OWIN application running as a Windows Service, and this did not work either. The command certainly gets called, but then the OS kills the process. Do you have a repository on github with this code working?

Comment: in method  *FileToPDF*  file.get refrence is missing not found getting error

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, As I said, it's not the best solution. This is what I had 3 years ago. Feel free to enlighten us with a better answer that will actually help people.

Comment: The answer typically given to this question is - use the Adobe SDK or a similar library. Better yet, use a reporting library - or an RDLC control. The same applied 3 4-5 years ago. Launching a processs isn't just a performance problem, it's also a huge security risk. Starting a *web browser* on the *server* just to render a PDF is also needlessly convoluted

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using [NReco.PhantomJS](https://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx), which provides a .NET wrapper for PhantomJS, you can do this very succinctly.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadPdf() {
    var phantomJS = new PhantomJS();
    try {
        var temp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),
            Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), "pdf")); //must end in .pdf
        try {
            await phantomJS.RunAsync(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/rasterize.js"),
                new[] { "https://www.google.com", temp });
            return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(temp), "application/pdf");
        }
        finally {
            System.IO.File.Delete(temp);
        }
    }
    finally {
        phantomJS.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and a commercial license is required.

Comment: @Tom Depends on your application, per their FAQ it "can be used for FREE in single-deployment projects (websites, intranet/extranet) or applications for company's internal business purposes (redistributed only internally inside the company)."

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very basic code to generate a PDF using Phantom.JS but you can find more information here: https://buttercms.com/blog/generating-pdfs-with-node

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("http://www.google.com", function start(status) {
page.render('google_home.pdf, {format: 'pdf', quality: '100'});
phantom.exit();
});
```