# Generating PDFs using Phantom JS in .NET on live server - NOTE: works fine locally

Tags: asp.net, windows, phantomjs, umbraco

I'm using Felipe's example on the following page and it works fine locally.
[Generating PDFs using Phantom JS on .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646375/generating-pdfs-using-phantom-js-on-net-applications)

However, phantomjs does not create the pdf on the server. The website we're attempting to add this feature to is built using the Umbraco CMS. Any idea in terms of permission or setting changes needed in order to get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is the problem? What errors do you see? What versions do you have? There is too little information to diagnose the problem. Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)) in the rasterize script. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and I apologize for the lack of information. The version of Phantomjs is 1.9.2. I've downloaded version 2.0, and will have to give that a try on Monday. 

However, I assume the issue was actually running the exe file. I've also tried the following, but couldn't get Notepad to load on the server (works fine locally).  

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe");

I'm assuming that the issue is a security/permissions issue and not any issues with Phantomjs.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include more information when you have them.